# Neo4j runs as root

Tags: ubuntu, neo4j

I've installed Neo4j testing on my brand new Ubuntu 13.10 minimal server.
Usually Neo4j runs as the neo4j user, which is there, but mine runs as root.

The configuration is default.

How can I fix that?

---

## Update

I do see a service running as `neo4j` and in `/etc/security/limits.conf` I have:

```
neo4j   soft    nofile  40000
neo4j   hard    nofile  40000
```

But I still see the warnings about *Max 1024 open files allowed* and *not changing user*:

```
$ sudo service neo4j-service restart
 * Restarting Neo4j Graph Database neo4j
WARNING: Max 1024 open files allowed, minimum of 40 000 recommended. See the Neo4j manual.
Using additional JVM arguments:  -server -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Dorg.neo4j.server.properties=conf/neo4j-server.properties -Djava.util.logging.config.file=conf/logging.properties -Dlog4j.configuration=file:conf/log4j.properties -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
Starting Neo4j Server...WARNING: not changing user
process [2398]... waiting for server to be ready.... OK.
http://localhost:7474/ is ready.
```

Comment: How did you install it? With apt-get, puppet or the tarball distribution?

Comment: I installed it with `apt-get` on an Ubuntu 13.10.

Comment: Try to reboot your server, some times the new limits confs don't apply properlt, and a reboot solves it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does "WARNING: not changing user" mean in Neo4j?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28995662/what-does-warning-not-changing-user-mean-in-neo4j)

Comment: reboot worked for me